# SSIS with C# try to get row count for each file

Tags: c#, ssis, count, record

iam doing the SSIS pakage and i did most the work via C# but what im trying to add is the record count for each output text file. what ever i try never works, i get an error or i get the count of the first out put file on all files. need help please. Thanks
this is my script

```
                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;


                    //  Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "DataTable Rows", RecordsInserted.ToString(), "", 0, ref fireAgain);

                 //   

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                            }
                            if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                            }
                          //  RecordsInserted = dt.Rows.Count;
                          //  Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "DataTable Rows", RecordsInserted.ToString(), "", 0, ref fireAgain);

                        }

                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    }
                     /////////////////////
                    sw.Write(",Insurance," + rctn);
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                   // sw.Write("Row count: " + RowCount.ToString());
              this is some of what i tried but nothing works for me


                    //       sw.Write("Row count: " + RowCount.ToString());

                    sw.Close();
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your code example looks incomplete, but I noticed there is no declaration of `RowCount` anywhere. Is it something like this you need:

```
sw.Write("Row count: " + d_table.Rows.Count.ToString());
```